# PDO run script from .sql file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-7.2

How correctly run sql file for insert in MySQL?
Try use PDO:

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "planets_test";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
# MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
$query = file_get_contents("planets_db.sql");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Where planets_db.sql" is script generated PHPmyAdmin?

Script not return error, but table not created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a script you can execute SQL with the following code:

```
try {
     $mysql_host = "localhost";
     $mysql_database = "planets_test";
     $mysql_user = "root";
     $mysql_password = "";
     $dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
     $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
     $query = file_get_contents("planets_db.sql");
     $dbh->exec($query);
     print("Created $table Table.\n");

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();//Remove or change message in production code
}
```

If there is an error it should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: trying to execute an empty query." . Filename is correct. Script correct too.

Comment: Try to print out the file contents to make sure there is something there: echo file_get_contents("planets_db.sql") . PHP_EOL;

Comment: your `$sql` should be `$query`.

Comment: @Jakumi nice catch

Comment: yeah, the only problem I see is, that the sql file probably has more than exactly one sql statement (i suppose the "insert" in the problem description implies that) and thus the `$dbh->exec()` will probably not work as expected, since it's for single statements only, iirc

Answer (score -1):

I checked your code in my PC. Nothing found any error. Please check your SQL file in the same directory or is it correct SQL file.

Comment: This file was generated from phpMyAdmin. If I pass text as qwery, table was created.

Comment: You can use following command in the terminal to generate correct SQL file. 
mysqldump -uroot -p database_name > planets_db.sql